# Seachable RecycleView ссылка на пустой лист

Tags: android, массивы, recyclerview, search

Переписываю адаптер и активити обычного RecycleView на тот что с поиском и не могу понять где сделал ошибку. В логах пишет что я ссылаюсь на пустой массив. Объясните где нужно сослаться на тот массив.

```
    public class Material extends BaseActivity implements DialogUtilities.OnCompleteListener, BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler{

        private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
        private ArrayList<String> mImageUrls = new ArrayList<>();
        EditText editText;
        RecyclerView recyclerv_view;
        private RecycleViewAdapter adapter;
    @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.materials);
            initImageBitmaps();

            recyclerv_view = findViewById(R.id.recyclerv_view);

            recyclerv_view.setAdapter(adapter);

            editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
            editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    filter(s.toString());
                }
            });
            recyclerv_view.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        private void filter(String text) {
            ArrayList<String> filteredNames = new ArrayList<>();

            for (String s : mNames) {
                if (s.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                    filteredNames.add(s);
                }
            }
            adapter.filterList(filteredNames);
        }


        private void initImageBitmaps(){
            mNames = new ArrayList<>();
            //0
            mImageUrls.add("https://u.livelib.ru/reader/vwvw2008/o/fmhclhxy/o-o.jpeg");
            mNames.add(getString(R.string.base_krok));
            //1
            mImageUrls.add("https://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2015/01/17/589833/ae71f6d11c0ad38688daa0e17dd9b8be.jpg");
            mNames.add(getString(R.string.chemistry));
            //2
            mImageUrls.add("https://ukrinnovate.com/upload/website-science-or-innovation-article-image-201803191200.jpg");
            mNames.add(getString(R.string.hisology));
            //3
            mImageUrls.add("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/36spQsZ5pqQ/maxresdefault.jpg");
            mNames.add(getString(R.string.hygiena));
            //4
            mImageUrls.add("https://images.wallpaperscraft.ru/image/kletki_mikrobiologiya_struktura_113059_1920x1080.jpg");
            mNames.add(getString(R.string.micro));
            //5
            mImageUrls.add("https://dekart-school.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/biologiya-oge.jpg");
            mNames.add(getString(R.string.biology));

            initRecyclerView();
        }
        private void initRecyclerView(){

            RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerv_view);
            RecycleViewAdapter adapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(this, mNames, mImageUrls);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        }
}
```

и **АДАПТЕР**

```
public class RecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<String> mImageNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mImages = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    public RecycleViewAdapter (Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mImageNames, ArrayList<String> mImages) {
        this.mImageNames = mImageNames;
        this.mImages = mImages;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.material, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder (@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(mImages.get(position))
                .into(holder.image1);

        holder.image_name.setText(mImageNames.get(position));

        holder.parent_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view) {
                Intent intent;
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), BaseKrok.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Chemistry.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Histology.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Hygiene.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Microbiology.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Biology.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Anatomy.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Physiology.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), OperSurgery.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount () {
        return mImageNames.size();
    }


    public void filterList(ArrayList<String> filteredList) {
        mImageNames = filteredList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView image1;
        TextView image_name;
        CardView parent_layout;
        LinearLayout lin;
        public ViewHolder (@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
            image_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_name);
            parent_layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
            lin = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lin);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы сначала инициализируете `recyclerv_view` в `onCreate => initImageBitmaps() => initRecyclerView()`, в котором создаете локальный адаптер с данными и устанавливаете его для `recyclerv_view`, затем, там же в `onCreate`, переустанавливаете для `recyclerv_view` адаптер из приватного члена класса `Material` `private RecycleViewAdapter adapter;`, который, кстати, не создан, то есть `null`. В `filter(String text)` вы также обращаетесь к приватному члену класса, который объявлен, но не создан. Вероятно, создание адаптера, объявленного приватным членом класса, должно было происходить в методе `initRecyclerView()`, тогда в этом методе не нужно локально объявлять новый адаптер: вместо `RecycleViewAdapter adapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(this, mNames, mImageUrls);` нужно `adapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(this, mNames, mImageUrls);`
При этом не понятно, зачем вы в `onCreate` несколько раз переустанавливаете адаптер для `recyclerv_view`?

PS. `initImageBitmaps();` - выполняет 3 функции: инициализирует список изображений, инициализирует список наименований и еще инициализирует `recyclerView`. При этом название метода говорит только об одном действии - инициализация списка изображений, что мешает пониманию вашего кода и поиска проблем в дальнейшем. Совет: если уж разделили действия на методы, то в `onCreate` вызывайте их по-отдельности последовательно.

Answer (score 1):

Вы определили глобальные перепенные:

```
RecyclerView recyclerv_view;
private RecycleViewAdapter adapter;
```

Потом в `onCreate()` вы вызываете ваш метод `initBitmaps()`, в котором сначала инициализируете ваши листы и вызываете `initRecyclerView()` после этого. В этом методе вы объявляете новые локальные!!! переменные:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerv_view);
RecycleViewAdapter adapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(this, mNames, mImageUrls);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Где на вход адаптеру вы подаете инициализированные листы, но recyclerView и adapter вы никак не используете, и далее в `onCreate()` вы ирициализируете вашу глобальную переменную `recyclerv_view`, но не  инициализиуете глобальную переменную `adapter` и подаете его в `recyclerv_view`.

```
recyclerv_view = findViewById(R.id.recyclerv_view);

recyclerv_view.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Чтобы исправить, в методе `initRecyclerView()` сделайте инициализацию глобальных переменных, перепишите так:

```
private void initRecyclerView(){

    recyclerv_view = findViewById(R.id.recyclerv_view);
    adapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(this, mNames, mImageUrls);
    recyclerv_view.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerv_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}
```

И удалите из onCreate() это:

```
recyclerv_view = findViewById(R.id.recyclerv_view);

recyclerv_view.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: У меня появилась проблема с поисковиком, когда поисковик нашёл тот или иной компонент `RecycleView` он не переходит по том Элементе а по первом. Например нашло оно 30 позицию если оно с помощью поиска стоит первым оно перейдет на 1. Как закрепить за ним место?